# Is $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}$

Tags: general-topology, spheres

Is the punctured $3d$ space, $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}$, where $B_{\epsilon}$ is a closed ball of radius $\epsilon$?

I don't think so. This is because the origin and the ball are not homeomorphic, so I think their complements must also not be. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Is $B_\epsilon$ the open ball or the closed ball ? (though no matter what, your heuristic is not right : take any two non homeomorphic spaces $X,Y$ and consider $\coprod_{n\in \mathbb N} X \sqcup \coprod_{n\in \mathbb N}Y$, then you can remove one copy of $X$ and get the same thing, or remove one copy of $Y$ and get the same thing too : you can take the complements of nonhomeomorphic things and get homeomorphic things - and in fact if you take the closed ball, you'll see an even more natural example)

Comment: @Max $B_{\epsilon}$ is the closed ball

Comment: You might find it more intuitive that these sets are homeomorphic (even though the complements are not) if you consider the version of this problem over $\Bbb R^1$.

Comment: Interestingly, the fact that the complements of homeomorphic sets can be non-homeomorphic makes an appearance in knot-theory.  Two knots are considered the same when there complements are homotopy-equivalent, but each "knot itself" is a loop in $\Bbb R^3$ which is homeomorphic to the unit circle.

Comment: Interestingly, the fact that the complements of homeomorphic sets can be non-homeomorphic makes an appearance in General Relativity in questions like *"what is the topology of a black hole's singularity?"*.  There is no meaningful answer to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can map $\mathbb R^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ [continuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) to $\mathbb R^3\setminus B_\epsilon$ by means of $r\mapsto r+\epsilon$ provided $B_\epsilon$ is the closed ball and $r$ denotes the radial component of [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) in $\mathbb R^3$.  The inverse mapping is obviously $r\mapsto r-\epsilon$.

Moreover, similar applies to any dimension, i.e. to $\mathbb R^n$.

> I dont think so. This is because the origin and the ball are not homeomorphic

The origin and the ball are not in your ([open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set)) sets; hence it does not matter.  Would be different if their borders *were* part of the sets, because the first one would be just $\mathbb R^3$ in that case which is a open set whereas the second one would be neither open nor close.

**Note**: $r\mapsto r+\epsilon$ is short for $(r,\varphi,\theta)\mapsto (r+\epsilon,\varphi,\theta)$.

Comment: The function is required to have a continuous inverse too (which this happens to have)

Comment: This is not a homeomorphism and it's not well defined. $r+ \epsilon$ is not a defined operation.

Comment: @HelloDarkness the map $f(r,\theta) = (r + \epsilon, \theta)$ is a well-defined map on polar coordinates, and polar coordinates with $r>0$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$ correspond uniquely to points in the punctured plane.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see that they are homeomorphic (and perhaps another way to understand it) is to use $x\mapsto \frac{x}{||x||^2}$. This is a homeomorphism $\mathbb R^3\setminus B_\epsilon \to \mathrm{Int}(B_{1/\epsilon})\setminus \{0\}$ (the inverse is given by the same formula).

Now $\mathrm{Int}(B_{1/\epsilon})$ is an open ball, so it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$, so we get the desired result.

Essentially, with $\epsilon = 1$, you're turning $\mathbb R^3$ around itself along the radius $1$ sphere, $0$ becomes infinity and infinity becomes $0$. This allows me to understand better what's happening : since the "large sphere at infinity" can become $0$, but it can also become a small sphere, the two work the same way.

Note that this proof works for $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n\geq 1$.